# IntelliJ show JavaDocs tooltip on mouse over

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, intellij-idea

In Eclipse, when hovering over a method, variable, etc. a tooltip is displayed with the corresponding JavaDocs. Is there such a feature in IntelliJ?

Comment: You can put the cursor inside the method/variable and press ctrl+q (on PC) or ctrl+j (on mac).

Comment: Should be nice to have that popup while typing the parameters...

Comment: I am still unable to see this after enabling as mentioned below for 2017.1 EAP. I even restarted and nada, I hovered for long.

Comment: In case none of the answers are working, make sure that you're not still in a debugging session by accident, which was the case for me.

Answer (score 942, accepted):

For **IntelliJ 13**, there is a checkbox in Editor's page in IDE Settings

[image]

**EDIT:** For **IntelliJ 14**, the option has been moved to Editor > General page. It's the last option in the "Other" group. (For Mac the option is under the menu "IntelliJ Idea" > "Preferences").

**EDIT:** For **IntelliJ 16**, it's the second-to-last option in Editor > General > Other.

**EDIT:** For **IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.1**, it's been moved to Editor > General > Code Completion.
[image]

**EDIT:** For **IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.2, aka IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.3**, there are actually two options:

1. In Editor > General > Other (section) > **Show quick documentation on mouse move - delay 500 ms**

- Select this check box to show quick documentation for the symbol at caret. The quick documentation pop-up window appears after the specified delay.

1. In Editor > General > Code Completion (sub-item) > **Autopopup documention in 1000 ms, for explicitly invoked completion**

- Select this check box to have IntelliJ IDEA automatically show a pop-up window with the documentation for the class, method, or field currently highlighted in the lookup list. If this check box is not selected, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to show quick documentation for the element at caret.
- Quick documentation window will automatically pop up with the specified delay in those cases only, when code completion has been invoked explicitly. For the automatic code completion list, documentation window will only show up on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

**EDIT**: For **IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.3**, the first option is now located under Editor > Code Editing > Quick Documentation > **Show quick documentation on mouse move**

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, and was exactly what I was looking for when I googled my issue. This seems to be the most up-to-date solution.

Comment: File/Settings | IDE Settings / Editor. Check "Show quick doc on mouse move"

Comment: Thanks it works on 13.1 but Jesus, that is not intuitive at all.

Comment: Can anyone comment on why this isn't enabled _by default_? I thought that IntelliJ simply didn't have the feature. It should be opt-out, enabled by default.

Comment: Anybody know where it is in IntelliJ 14? The Editor page only has links to its subpages, and the option doesn't seem to be in any of them.

Comment: The problem is, it doesn't STICK! As soon as I move the mouse away, it disappears. This is unlike Eclipse, where I can move into the doc pop-up and make it stick - very useful for reading longer docs and navigating. How can I get IntelliJ doc pop-up to stick?! Starting to hate the fact that Android Studio is now official...

Comment: It can't compare to eclipses, simply garbage compared to. Also if you edit String resources and copy text from somewhere else it will pop up and take focus so you have to click inside studio again, (and again and again). Can be extremly anoing, and drive me to disable it T_T

Comment: That's one ugly popup X-(

Comment: To fix the disappearing immediately on mouse move problem, hold down Ctrl while on your way to the popup. That makes it stick around for me on Linux IntelliJ 14

Comment: It should be enabled by default.

Comment: @ADTC I discovered how to stick the pop up. Find my answer (with images) in [How to keep popup on one screen in Intellij IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36448311/1983854). The key here is using the pin!

Comment: As we are talking about "hovering" it should be called "hover" or so, so that it become searchable in preferences. I spent quite sometime offline searching for this setting. Had to go online and google up this...

Comment: **UPDATE** For IntelliJ IDEA **2016.3.3** this setting is located in _Settings > Editor > General_, scroll down to "_Other_" section and check "**Show quick documentation on mouse move**".

Comment: The above screenshot also applies for version 2017.1.x

Comment: [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[A] and type "Show quick doc on mouse move". You'll be redirect to the settings panel, mark the corresponding option

Comment: @MartinWickman  What is the difference between this one and "Show quick doc on mouse move"?

Comment: This very basic feature doesn't work well at all in IntelliJ. It overlays exceptions and other messages, and if you hit Esc it removes everything... :-(

Comment: I found that enabling this option caused my IntelliJ to get INCREDIBLY slow. Be warned, if you enable this option and you later notice a big slowdown.

Comment: Is there any way to disable the pop-up when hovering over an error or warning? The documentation goes on top of error/warning message.

Comment: The problem with enabling it by default is that it can mess up your typing.  When it popped up in eclipse it didn't seem so intrusive, with intellij it actually does something strange  Haven't spent a lot of time playing with it, I just know I don't like it enough that I re-disabled it. :)

Comment: **IntelliJ 2018.2.4 (Community Edition):** `Preferences > Editor > General: Other (subsection) > Show quick documentation on mouse move`

Comment: Danny Bullis comment ^ works on **2018.3.4CE** as well

Comment: in case where "show quick docs on mouse move" Editor -> General and on right hand you have to :  **SCROLL THE PANE DOWN**!

Answer (score 149):

Up until IntelliJ version 11, no, not just by hovering over it. If the cursor is inside the method- or attribute name, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> will show the JavaDoc on *nix and Windows. On MacOSX, this is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Quote: *"No, the only way to see the full javadoc is to use Quick Doc (Ctrl-Q)."* -- http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/121174

### EDIT

Since IntelliJ 12.1, this *is* possible. See @ADNow's answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'd rather use the keyboard than mouse hovers.

Answer (score 101):

It is possible in 12.1.

Find **idea.properties** in the BIN folder inside of wherever your IDE is installed, e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ\bin

Add a new line to the end of that file:

```
auto.show.quick.doc=true
```

Start IDEA and just hover your mouse over something:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly for me in 12.1.5 Ultimate, but is there a way to change this exposed in the settings menu?

Comment: This does not do anything in my 133.79 Beta on Linux.

Comment: Any idea why I am not getting Syntax highlighting in the documentation popup? http://stackoverflow.com/q/23086511/238768

Answer (score 28):

After doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, you can

1. Pin the tooltip (top right corner)
2. Check *Docked Mode* (under gear in top right after pinning)
3. Size as desired
4. Click icon for *Auto show documentation for selected item*

Then when you move your cursor, the documentation will appear in this box.  It costs you a little screen real estate, but I find it's worth it.

I'd post a screenshot but SO won't let me post images.

Answer (score 25):

For Intellij 15, use the checkbox in `File > Settings > Editor > General` option **Show quick documentation on mouse move**.

[image]

You can also get there by typing "quick" or something similar in the search box:

[image]

Comment: This one works. But what "Autopopup documentation in in(ms)" in other answers stands for?

Comment: @Serob_b I am not sure what you mean here.

Comment: In my version of Intellij (2017.1.3) there is an option that you are talking about, but also "Autopopup documentation in(ms):"  option in Editor > General > Code Completion (as accepted answer informs). So, what is the difference between these two? Just checking the second one (Autopopup) didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Serob_b they are the same. I asked it in [What is the difference between Quick documentation and Autopopup documentation in Intellij IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44326900/1983854).

Comment: Thanks. I've actually figured out that "Autopopup documentation in (ms)" is for ctrl + space and has nothing to do with mouse hover, and of course "Show quick documentation on mouse move" is what shows docs on hover.
 In Intellij 2017

Answer (score 24):

In Intellij13, you can use Editor configuration like below:
[image]

Comment: In terms of getting exactly the same UX as eclipse, this looks like the best answer to me .. thanks !

Comment: This one works. But what "Autopopup documentation in in(ms)" in other answers stands for?

Answer (score 14):

IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3 Ultimate: 
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, then choose `Editor\General` choose `Show quick domentation on mouse move`
[image]

Tips: Look at the top right conner (gear icon) at JavaDoc pop-up window, You can choose:
- Show Toolbar 
- Pinded Mode 
- Docked Mode 
- Floatting Mode 
- Split Mode 
[image]

Answer (score 9):

Adding on to what ADNow said. On the Macintosh:

1. Right click on IntelliJ IDEA 12
2. Click on the **Show Package Contents** menu option
3. Open the **bin** folder
4. Open **idea.properties**
5. Add the line:

   auto.show.quick.doc=true

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way, at least for me, was:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Type: *show document*
- *Show quick documentation on mouse move* (set it to ON)

Answer (score 7):

From **IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.1.5, aka IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5, till 2019.3** ,  there are actually two options under File -> Preferences:

1. In Editor > General > Other (section) > **Show quick documentation on mouse move - delay 500 ms**

   - Select this check box to show quick documentation for the symbol at caret. The quick documentation pop-up window appears after the specified delay.
2. In Editor > General > Code Completion (sub-item) > **Auto-display documentation in 1000 ms**

   - Select this check box to have IntelliJ IDEA automatically show a pop-up window with the documentation for the class, method, or field currently highlighted in the lookup list. If this check box is not selected, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to show quick documentation for the element at caret.
   - Quick documentation window will automatically pop up with the specified delay in those cases only, when code completion has been invoked explicitly. For the automatic code completion list, documentation window will only show up on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

In IntelliJ IDEA 14, it has moved to: File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> "Show quick doc on mouse move"

Answer (score 3):

In Intellij 2019, I did:  File > Settings > Editor > General option Show quick documentation on mouse move.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: This is the answer for 2019.3. I love playing hide-and-seek with this feature every major release! Thank you JetBrains <3

Comment: @MattStephenson now to find it again for 2020.2 >_<

Answer (score 2):

File-->Settings-->Editor

Check "*Show quick doc on mouse*"

Now when you put the mouse over a method a tooltip with the documentation will appear. Sometimes the tooltip size is too small and you will have to resize it moving the mouse down to the bottom of the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

IDEA has "**find action**":

Open "Help" menu, type "doc", move cursor to "**Quick Documentation**" it will be highlighted.

Also "find action" can be called from hot key (you can find it in settings->hotkeys)

Answer (score 1):

On mac in IntelliJ Ultimate (trial) 14 I have mine under `Settings > Editor > General > Code completion`. The tooltip short is F1 on my laptop.

It's called "Autopopup documentation in (ms):"

[image]

Comment: This does not show docs, just the possible method invocation and their parameter types.

Comment: how do you "explicitly invoke completion"

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: This is just code completion with types right? No doc info?

Comment: It's supposed to show the JavaDoc, it does for me. The JavaDoc window will popup after 1000ms, now you may have to have a look at where it pops up. Sometimes it pops up as a tab in the right toolbar by the maven tab.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe because I am using Scala.

Comment: I can't verify that plugins will work. It doesn't work for the JS/Node plugin either so that's probably why.

Answer (score 1):

A note for Android Studio (2.3.3 at least) users, because this page came up for my google search "android studio hover javadoc", and android studio is based on Intellij:

See File->Settings->Editor->General: "show quick documentation on mouse moves",
rather than File->Settings->Editor->General->Code Completion
"Autopopup documentation in (ms) for explicitly invoked completion" 
and "Autopopup in (ms)", which has been previously talked about.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many ways mentioned here, especially the preference - editor - general - code completion - show documentation popup in.. isn't working in **version 2019.2.2**

Finally, i am just using `F1` while caret is on the type/method and it displays the documentation nicely. This is not ideal but helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In 2020.1 there is [in editor javadocs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-code-documentation.html#toggle-rendered-view) rendering has been added. Screen shots borrowed from intellij documentation.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On my IntelliJ U on Mac I need to point with cursor on some method, variable etc. and press [cntrl] or [cmd] key. Then click on the link inside popup window which appeared to see JavaDocs

Answer (score 0):

All of the above methods are useful but one basic thing missing you need to have **src.zip** in your JDK (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171). I assumed it comes preinstalled but for some reason, it was not present in my installation. Another thing to check is if your project is using the specified (1.8.0_171 in this case) JDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on MacOS, the fix was for me to disable:
Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance -> Support screen readers
[image]

Answer (score -1):

**The answer is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (NOT <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>)**

Someone else posted this answer on JetBrains forum:
The idea is a different IDE. Try to discover its features and try to make the best of it, rather than trying to emulate whatever you used before.
For the most part, Idea has very high usability (much better than Eclipse IMHO) and is streamlined for supporting code editing as best as possible (rather than relying on wizards too much for example).

- Javadoc: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>
- A quick view of the implementation:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>
- Show context:  <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>
- Show parameters (in a method call):  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>
- Show error description.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>

... plus many more shortcuts to navigate in code and different idea views.

I think it rather nice that you can see just the specific bit of information you are interested in with a simple keystroke.
Have a look at the menus which will also show the possibly modified shortcuts for your keymap.

0
Avatar
Jens Voß
Created June 12, 2008, 09:26
And, elsandros, in addition to what Stephen writes: Since you seem to be interested in IDEA's keyboard shortcuts, I highly recommend the "Key Promoter" plugin which helps you memorize the relevant shortcuts quickly.

Also very useful is the "Goto Action" feature, invoked by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>. In the popup, you can enter a keyword (e.g. "Javadoc"), and the IDE tells you the available actions matching your search, along with keyboard shortcuts and the containing action groups (which often also give you a clue about how to navigate to the action using the menu).

Comment: The best answer is: eg. Mercedes Sara= new Mercedes();  1. put your cursor in (). 2. Press ctrl + P 3. Press alt + P  result: now all variables are auto-formatted and you can type the values while reading the variables. (build 2018)

Comment: Disagree that this is the best answer. The question was for a mouse hover over a symbol, which is provided OOTB in Eclipse. What I typically find is that I'm interested in something that's on the screen, but not under the cursor. So, to move the cursor to the symbol (mouse movement), type a short cut (keyboard), and then mouse back to where I was editing (another mouse movement) is too much work. A single mouse movement to get the information I need is perfect, as I can resume typing immediately.