# Intellij IDEA show javadoc automatically

Tags: autocomplete, intellij-idea, javadoc

When I am coding at Netbeans it autocompletes the code and show Javadocs. However when I am using Intellij IDEA if I click **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>** I can see the auto-complete and if I click **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>** I can see the javadoc seperately.

Is it possible to see the Javadoc of element whenever I see auto-complete or click **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>** at Intellij IDEA as like Netbeans?

Comment: +1 for mentioning the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Btw: on OS X the shortcut for javadoc insight is ctrl+j.

Comment: On Window click alt+tertiary-mouse-button on a symbol in question to open javadoc insight.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ tooltip shows JavaDocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615516/intellij-tooltip-shows-javadocs)

Answer (score 170, accepted):

`Settings` | `Editor` | `General` |`Code Completion` | `Show the documentation popup in __ ms`.
[image: Settings screenshot]

Older versions:
`Settings` | `Editor` | `General` |`Code Completion` | `Autopopup documentation in (ms)`.

[image: Settings screenshot]

**UPDATE**: latest versions have an [option to show JavaDoc on mouse move](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11053374/104891).

Comment: It's OK. When I click ctrl + space it shows both code completion and javadoc. However when I don't click ctrl + space it autocomplets but doesn't show javadoc?

Comment: Yes, this behavior is by design, when automatic completion is invoked, JavaDoc is not shown.

Comment: It would be nice if it was possible to see both javadoc and code completion, thanks.

Comment: I added it as a request: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-76223?projectKey=IDEA

Comment: @kamaci : it works also without code completion, on mouse over : see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22759295/1677594 (*show quick doc on mouse move*)

Comment: Still accurate ten years later, if someone's wondering.

Answer (score 14):

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code completion.

Check *Autopopup documentation in (ms)* and choose delay.

Answer (score 14):

Show Javadoc in IntelliJ IDEA 14:

- When you write code:

  `File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion -> Autopopup documentation in (ms)`

It's only available when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> It's more usable if you select the pin icon when it popups. The documentation window will be added to the tabs on the right. Later on I recommend to resize the window and to uncheck the `Pinned` property.

- On mouse hover:

  `File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Show quick documentation on mouse move`

Comment: The idea of pinning it to the side of the window is very useful