# How to see JavaDoc in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, javadoc

I just switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ.   IntelliJ lacks one feature from Eclipse - when you put your mouse over a method, Eclipse shows javadoc info. I think the way to show it is to use a shortcut - <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, but when I click it, I get something wrong as on the screen shot below. Please advise me on how I can quickly get javadoc information. I need to at least know what type a method returns.

[image]

Answer (score 721, accepted):

Use `View` | **Quick Documentation** or the corresponding keyboard shortcut
(by default: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> on Windows/Linux
and <kbd>F1</kbd> on macOS in the recent IDE versions, before was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>).
Better ee the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#inline-quick-documentation) for more information.

It's also possible to enable automatic JavaDoc popup on **explicit** (invoked by a shortcut) code completion in `Settings` | `Editor` | `General` | `Code completion` (**Autopopup documentation**):

[image: autopopup documentation]

Yet another way to see the quick doc is **on mouse move**:

[image: on mouse move]

Comment: +1, could not find `Preferences` in IntelliJ Idea CE for Android.

Comment: Win7 = Position cursor before class -> CTRL+q

Comment: I was dumb enough to follow the above advice on Mac. Cmd+q. Boom! Quit IntelliJ. Genius..

Comment: It is CTRL+J on Mac.

Comment: When I do this for String.compareToIgnoreCase(), I only see the signature, not the explanation of the result. Do I need to change a setting to pull in the full JavaDoc?

Comment: In fact, replace ``Preferences`` by ``File | Settings`` (v 13.1)

Comment: @GuillaumeHusta it depends on the OS, `Preferences` on Mac, `Settings` on Windows/Linux.

Comment: @CrazyCoder OK ! Thanks for the precision. That's strange to have different labels depending on the OS ?!? But that's true on the official online help page : http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/settings-preferences-dialog.html !

Comment: Ctrl+q works on GNU/Linux too

Comment: In 14.0.2 it is File | Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion

Comment: The "Autopopup" (on mouseover) opens a completely new window (which steals focus), not a transient overlay that disappears when user moves the mouse or clicks outside the window. This is more disruptive than useful--so one of those last few things that I miss about Eclipse. I'm glad to learn about Ctrl-Q (which also closes the window), though. Very useful!

Comment: and I was thinking that intelliJ is better than Eclipse on every aspects.

Comment: Have you tried NetBeans? Eclipse is the worst. But IntelliJ suck pretty badly too. NetBeans is the one that annoy me the least. Also, I don't understand why this answer is approved. The question was how to make the popup happen on mouse over.

Comment: The suggestion that "It's also possible to enable automatic JavaDoc popup on code completion in Preferences | Editor | General | Code completion (Autopopup documentation)" doesn't work.   That is "For explicitly invoked completion", not random hover.

The *real* fix is in the answer below:
"Go to File/Settings, Editor, click on General. Scroll down, then ✔ Show quick documentation on mouse move."

Comment: Its unfortunate that IDEA doesn't enable it by default. Your Preferences menu might look different depending up on your edition - Community or Professional. Search bar in preferences will help.

Comment: Shortcut for macOS with IntelliJ 2017 EAP is now `F1` for *Quick Documentation* and `Shift+F1` for *External Documentation* (web browser).

Comment: Not sure how people use ```ctrl + j``` in real life. These keys are just too far on keyboard.

Comment: Can anyone explain the use of "Autopopup documentation..." in Code Completion?

Comment: @AndrewKirna when you invoke code completion using the keyboard shortcut (vs automatic), IDE will show you the popup documentation for the method/class you are trying to complete.

Comment: If you have a class open with Javadocs, `fn + F2` will pop up the said view window. Verified on a Mac and IDEA 2017.3.

Comment: Answer updated with latest shortcuts from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#inline-quick-documentation, better check docs.

Answer (score 144):

Alternatively you can position your cursor on the item and show JavaDoc using

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

which is the default shortcut.

Edit: As Methical mentioned *on Mac* the shortcut is

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> (<kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> not <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>)

Comment: this works like how eclipse pulls up the documentation, not the top voted answer. Thank you!

Comment: In Mac F1 works equal than Ctrl + J to show JavaDoc

Comment: @jfuentes since we don't have F1 on Macbook keyboards by default ^ + J works

Answer (score 142):

Go to `File/Settings`, `Editor`, click on `General`.

Scroll down, then ✔ `Show quick documentation on mouse move`.

[image]

Comment: OK with this tip we have the exact *same behavior* as with *Eclipse* (on mouse over)

Comment: Feature added since v13.0. See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/editor.html

Comment: On a mac, replace File/Settings with IntelliJ/Preferences

Comment: But the feature is terrible as of 14.0. Sometimes they interfere with your ability to click on things, or get stuck and will never disappear.

Comment: You don’t have to expand the “Editor” menu group. You will not find this setting in one of the its entries. You have to select the *Editor* “group” **itself** and it will show a settings page on the right where the option is.

Answer (score 24):

There is nice feature which shows quick documentation when your mouse is over element.

**IntelliJ 14**

Editor / General -> Show quick documentation on mouse move

**Older versions**

Add the following line to idea.properties file:

```
auto.show.quick.doc=true
```

Answer (score 10):

Configuration for **IntelliJ IDEA CE 2016.3.4** to enable JavaDocs on mouse hover. I am running IntelliJ IDEA on Mac OS but believe that Linux/Windows should have similar options.

**Autopopup docs:**
`IntelliJ IDEA` > `Preferences` > `Editor` > `General` > `Code Completion`

[image]

**Documentation on mouse move:**
`IntelliJ IDEA` > `Preferences` > `Editor` > `General`

[image]

NOTE: Please hit **Apply** button to apply these settings

Answer (score 6):

For me, it wasn't just getting the javadoc window to open, but also getting the complete javadoc to present.  You may still get a sparse javadoc that is based solely on the method signature if you are importing libraries from a Maven repository and do not tell Idea to include the javadocs in the download.  Be sure to tick the "JavaDocs" option in the "Download Library From Maven Repository" dialog, which can be found under Project Structure -> Projtect Settings -> Libraries.

Answer (score 5):

To best mirror Eclipses functionality, enable the following settings:

- **IDE Settings/Editor** -> **Other.Show quick doc on mouse move**
- **IDE Settings/Editor/Code Completion** -> **Autopopup Documentation**

To see the javadoc in the autocomplete menu, hit '.' to get the popup, then hover over the object you are working with, once you get the javadoc popup, you can select an item in the popup to switch the javadoc over. Not ideal... But its something.

As another note. The search functionality of the options menu is very useful. Just type in 'doc' and you will see all the options for doc.

Also, searching for "autopopup doc" will not only find each of the options, but it will also highlight them in the menu. Pretty awesome!

---

**Edit:**
Going beyond the initial question, this might be useful for people who just want quick and easy access to the docs.

After using this for a few more days, it seems just getting used to using the hotkey is the most efficient way. It will pop up the documentation for anything at the spot of where your text input marker is so you never have to touch the mouse. This works in the intellisense popup as well and will stay up while navigating up and down.

Personally, Ctrl+Q on windows was not ideal so I remapped it to Alt+D. Remaping can be done under IDE Settings/Keymap. Once in the keymap menu, just search for Quick Documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Go to **Settings -> Editor -> General** then enable **Show quick documentation on mouse move**

Answer (score 4):

**IntelliJ IDEA 15** added this feature

Now it is available as EAP.

As you can see in the picture below, the caret position doesn't influence the cursor position:
[image]

[This feature](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66333#) was implemented in [IntelliJ IDEA 15 142.4675.3 Release Notes](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+15+142.4675.3+Release+Notes).

Answer (score 2):

The closest to Eclipse will be **Ctrl+Button2 Click (Scroll click)**

It's called Quick Doc in IntelliJ, I wish guys from JetBrains one day add quick doc like Eclipse with **Ctrl+Mouse Move** it's so much better.

In my case only with only mouse move is a bit annoying, so if you search in **Preferences/Settings --> Keymap** for "quick documentation" you will find:

- Win-Linux: "*Ctrl+Q*" and "*Ctrl+Button2 Click*" (Scroll click)
- Mac: "*Ctrl+J*" and "*Ctrl+Button2 Click*" (Scroll click)

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that selecting the method name and pressing F2(Quick Documentation) dispalys it's JavaDoc. 
I am using Intellij 2016, and Eclipse Keymap