# Getting info about a Class in IntelliJ IDE by hovering over it

Tags: intellij-idea

In EClipse if I hold the mouse over a class name I get some hint like the picture below about it:

[image]

But with doing the same I don't get that hint box in IntellijIDEA.(Mac edition)
Is there a setting somewhere to set this? It is really helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to see JavaDoc in IntelliJ IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053144/how-to-see-javadoc-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can press **CTRL + Q** when hovering above a class name to show a popup with more information.

Comment: Thanks, does Mac version have a different shortcut?  Command-Q wants to Quit the IDE and control-Q doesn't do anything.

Comment: It's possible, I'm working under Linux atm. You can look up or change the shortcut by going to Settings > Keymap and search for Quick Documentation.

Comment: Thanks, the keyword I needed to know was "Quick Documentation" ..atm it is CTRL-J

Answer (score 10):

For anybody new finding this question there is also an option for it
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To know the classname and it's initial declaration within the scope, use Ctrl + J (Mac OS)