# How to make javaDoc in IntelliJ IDEA smart as Eclipse?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

By checking [How to see JavaDoc in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053144/how-to-see-javadoc-in-intellij-idea#), I can enable JavaDoc popup whenever I hover a mouse on an java type.

However, there are several problems about the popup window:
1) It can not disappear when I move over my mouse.
2) It has a fixed window size instead of adjusting itself automatically based on the content.

In Eclipse, there are no such problems. Is there any solution ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The size isn't fixed. Yes, it isn't automatic, but websites aren't either. You can however resize it by dragging the borders.

Comment: So...did you read the answer?  It's entirely explained in there; you can use the Quick Documentation shortcut to get what you're after.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still can not get the answer after I re-read the link.  In Eclipse, whenever my mouse hover over a method definition, it will popup the javadoc automatically; when my mouse mover to other place and I click, the popup window will disappear. However, in IDEA, I have to explicitly close the popup window.      BTW, I'm just talking about mouse, not keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Another issue is that: the popup window's location is fixed when I switch from one method to another. However, in Eclipse, the popup window's location can be placed under the target method automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The closest to Eclipse will be **Ctrl+Button2 Click** (Scroll click)

Hope JetBrains add that feature Eclipse-like soon.