# What is Android Studio shortcut to show function return type, parameter type & names all at the same time?

Tags: android, android-studio

While I'm typing a function name:

```
String response;
response.split|    // *** '|' denotes the caret position ***
```

Android Studio shows its declaration and the documentation. I can see return type, parameter names&types and doc all at the same time:

[image]

But when I'm inside parentheses, it shows parameters but no return type. (Cmd+P or Ctrl+P)

```
String response;
response.split(|)
```

[image]

If I press F1 (mac) or Ctrl+Q(win) inside parentheses, sometimes it  doens't show anything because there's an error (for not completing the line), but when it shows it shows return type & parameter type but omits parameter names.

[image]

Does anyone know the shortcut(and its name) to show the first one - return type, parameter types, and (possibly) documentation all at the same time - while I'm inside parentheses?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see JavaDoc in IntelliJ IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053144/how-to-see-javadoc-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: @ChrisStillwell The link talks about quick doc - F1(mac) or Ctrl+Q(win) - which is the third image I posted. When the function has multiple signatures, it shows only return type & parameter type. What I would like to see are the return type, the parameter names, and possibly its documentation all at the same time while in parentheses.

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Comment: Thx for confirming the feature is non-existent, @ChiefTwoPencils. I chose your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be out of our control. Based on Intellij IDEA 15.0.4 it's possible but not consistent; at first glance it seems the complete documentation as you desire is given by default for methods which have a single implementation while methods with multiple list them.

This is for `List#add` (multiple implementations):

[image]

---

And this is for `List#get` (single implementation):

[image]

---

Another example just to begin to confirm my thoughts, here's `Iterator<T>#forEachRemaining` (also single implementation):

[image]

---

Perhaps it would be too cluttered to be useful if each were listed.

As you may know, it's possible to jump to a single one in the list by tabbing and pressing enter on the one you want. Then you can use the arrows at the top to go back to see another. Not ideal but better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought the feature must be present in IntelliJ  & Android Studio, but apparently, it seems not. Should file a request so that it show parameter names along with parameter types when there are multiple implementations.

Comment: @wooohoh, they work with agility so if enough users agree it will likely be done. Good luck

Answer (score 8):

I guess this is the one you are looking for, **CTRL + space and hover move to any option**

[image]

**CTRL + P**

[image]

**CTRL + Q**

[image]

**CTRL + space**

[image]

Comment: Hi @penguin, I like your name. Anyway, Ctrl + Space shows what I can use for parameters. Ctrl + P shows function parameters. Ctrl + Q is closest to what I want but it shows parameter types but omit parameter names. What I would like to see are return type, parameter types & names all at the same time.