# Getting forwarded to Python doc when pressing F1 in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm used to get to get forwarded to the documentation of the method under the cursor in VS or QtCreator when I hit F1.

Is it possible to configure PyCharm to behave in a similar way so that it shows the corresponding page of https://docs.python.org of the method currently under the cursor?

Comment: I think you are looking for "Quick documentation".  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053144/how-to-see-javadoc-in-intellij-idea

Comment: As I'm aware those webpages are generated from the doc strings of modules the objects the modules contain.