# IntelliJ - show the method description and comments when the code popup appears

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, documentation, markup

I want the popup window of the available methods to show the method description when I scroll to them.

[image]

(Obviously this will only work when the method itself has the necessary comments and markup.)

```
/**
 * If a value is present in this {@code Optional}, returns the value,
 * otherwise throws {@code NoSuchElementException}.
 *
 * @return the non-null value held by this {@code Optional}
 * @throws NoSuchElementException if there is no value present
 *
 * @see Optional#isPresent()
 */
public T get() {
```

I want it to behave like this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see JavaDoc in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053144/how-to-see-javadoc-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: I already have that selected. Doesn't do what I'm asking. It only shows the available methods

Comment: added another pic

Comment: Got it, but why would you want it specifically at the bottom. It covers the screen since that's what you've asked for at that time. Just the point over UX is something opinion based in that case. IMHO, its fine, I do read about the entire doc in a new pop-up.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `Quick Definition View` in addition to the simple completion lookup.

So,

- `CRTL` + `SPACE` to produce the lookup you showed in your question
- Then `CRTL` + `SHIFT` + `SPACE` to show the `Quick Definition View`, for example:

[image]

This shows the available methods and their documentation.

Comment: thats a horrible UX. It will cover 90% of my ide screen everytime. I need a small description at the bottom like the second picture I just added :).

Comment: @glitch Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053144/how-to-see-javadoc-in-intellij-idea?

Answer (score 1):

Once you select the method using `CRTL + SPACE (control + SPACE in mac)`, you can press `CRTL + Q (F1 in mac)` to view quick documentation.