# Is there a "quick documentation" shortcut for VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In some IDEs, Intellij IDEA for example, pressing `control + j` will display the docstring like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053144/how-to-see-javadoc-in-intellij-idea). How do I get similar functionality for VS code?

Answer (score 41):

The best I've found is <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> for mac

Comment: this also works for ubuntu currently (ctrl + shift + space)

Comment: This shows me a quick reference of the parent widget on Windows.

Answer (score 35):

### Settings

- This three settings in the picture will help.
- Click to thing that you want to its documentation with mouse
- Use keybinding that given below

[image]

### Show Hover

[image: Show Hover]

### Definition Preview Hover

[image: Definition Preview Hover]

Comment: Worth noting that you have to remove the control+K shortcut if you have the vim extension installed

Answer (score 21):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> might work. You can change to your favorite hotkey combination by change setting in Keyboard Shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

Comment: For MacOS, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> works for me.

Answer (score 14):

There are 2 ways in Visual Studio Code (version 1.34.0) to show quick documentation:

1. short version -> mouse hover elements which you want to lookup
2. long version -> after short version appears, press 'ctrl' key twice (if you press 'ctrl' key once, the long version documentation appears as long as you hold the 'ctrl' key)

Answer (score 13):

The VSCode shortcuts Command is `Show Hover`, just change it to `^ j` or whatever and you are ready to go.

Don't forget to resolve the conflicting shortcuts if any.