# Command to toggle docstring in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

What command do I have to use in VSCode to toggle the docstring?

I have searched in settings for docstring, help but nothing that makes sense shows up.

Answer (score 16):

I guess you want parameter suggestions for a method or function. 
Shortcut for mac is: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

See other question:
[Is there a "quick documentation" shortcut for VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48454981/is-there-a-quick-documentation-shortcut-for-vs-code)

For all shortcuts press: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>.

Comment: The command invoked is called 'trigger parameter hints'.

Comment: This seems to have now enabled some automatic pop up whenever I hover. Doing it again does not seem to disable this "feature".

Answer (score 15):

You can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>. This will execute the `editor.action.showHover` command and will display the same text that is displayed when you hover over for example a function. Unfortunately there seems to be **no** corresponding `editor.action.hideHover` command (I searched the  `keybindings.json`). But it should be possible to hide the text again by pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Comment: mac: cmd + K, cmd + I

Comment: This does not do anything.

Comment: The marker needs to be before the paranthesis when calling the above command. If | is the position of the marker, "a b c d".split(|) will not show a docstring, but "a b c d".split|() will.

Comment: @TomNorway and this is unfortunate! the `cmd + k cmd + I` docstring is color-formatted, but not callable from ( | ). `cmd + shift + space` is callable from ( | ), but not colorformatted. sigh

Comment: What do you mean by color-formatted? I can reproduce what you're saying about `|`, I get docstrings with color in them in both cases. Edit: Ah, I see a difference for e.g. `np.array()`.

Answer (score -4):

You can either install an extension/snippet to provide it (Python only right now) https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=njpwerner.autodocstring

Or you can create a [user-defined snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) and [assign it to a hotkey](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_9#_insert-snippets).

Comment: No what im after. When you hover over a function in java python etc you get a textbox showing that functions docstring. I would like to toggle this text using the keyboard insted of hover since im using vim mode.

Comment: What you're now describing is not a docstring. But maybe you want the hotkey `Control+Space`?