# Shortcut for getting a python function doc string in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I use browser to open Jupyter notebooks, I can use `Shift + Tab` shortcut to get a python function doc string; however, in VSCode, that shortcut does not work. Does anyone know which shortcut gives me the docstring there?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535763/command-to-toggle-docstring-in-vscode#:%7E:text=You%20can%20hit%20Ctrl%20%2B%20K,over%20for%20example%20a%20function) but cannot understand the suggested solution (what is `Ctrl + K Ctrl + I` ?)

Comment: that is the keybinding for that command Control-K followed by Control-I

Comment: @rioV8 you mean Ctrl+K and then Ctrl+ I ?

Comment: yes, Ctrl+K is the prefix

Comment: ok, now I can say (Ctrl + K Ctrl + I) does not work

Comment: if you are using a mac it is command k then command I (cmd+k cmd+i)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

shows the keyboard shortcuts that have been set up and help below it will show you how to change what you want to change

Answer (score 0):

When using VSCode in Windows, the default shortcut key for displaying the python function docstring is "`ctrl+k ctrl+i`". When using it, please place the mouse on the area of the python module or method that needs to be viewed (front or middle or back All works):

[image]

In addition, please check whether other shortcut keys of `"editor.action.showHover"` have been set in "`keybindings.json`".

Reference: [Keybindings in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_rich-languages-editing).