# How to display/preview a python docstring in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a Python project using VSCode and Jupyter notebooks.
When working in a notebook, I can bring up the docstring for a given method by pressing shift+tab.
This previews the same text as doing `print(method_name.__doc__)`, see screenshot below.

[image: Docstring preview in Jupyter notebook]

The above provides a clear picture of which arguments the method expects and what it returns, which is helpful to me.

I want to do the same thing in VSCode.
Looking at the answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49535763/3752268), there's a few hotkeys to view documentation (ctrl+k ctrl i, ctrl+space).
However, these do not display the same docstring, but something near-incomprehensible and not very helpful to me - see screenshot below.

What can I do to quickly preview that docstring in VSCode?

[image: Documentation preview attempt in VSCode]

Comment: Did you customize keybindings? i can't get docstring with shift+Tab in jupyter.

Comment: No, it just worked like that out of the box, on a number of different machines.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Please file a report in [github/vscode-python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues) for more help and share the link here.

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT was there an improvement made here? I still see docstrings similar to what is reported in this question and the most similar issue I could find was this one which doesn't have a resolution https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17932