# How to make IntelliJ display the Javadoc of autocompletion suggestions?

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc, code-completion

IntelliJ display Java code auto-completion suggestions in a drop-down menu after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>. All other IDEs manage to display the corresponding Javadoc if available. How to get IntelliJ to do that?

[How to see JavaDoc in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053144/how-to-see-javadoc-in-intellij-idea) refers to displaying it on a mouse hover event whereas I'm missing the Javadoc from code-completion suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you put a dot and the suggestions appear, press <kbd>F1</kbd> (which is the default shortcut for "Quick Documentation" in most keymaps). The documentation for the currently selected method then appears as a card as show in the image. Then you can either use the up/down arrow keys or start typing the method name to select it. The documentation card will reflect accordingly.

[image: intellij quick documentation]

You can also click on the pin icon on top right of the documentation card to expand it if required.

Comment: Opens Firefox (the default web broser) on Ubuntu 18.04 for `System.getenv` and `String.format`.

Comment: Ok, go to your preferences window and search for "Keymap". Within that, search for "Quick documentation". See what is the shortcut for you. Here is how mine looks; https://imgur.com/a/K2gFsNY

Comment: Also, on some laptops you may have to press Fn key to actually do an F1

Comment: That works (however, IntelliJ doesn't pick up the docs from the filesystem which makes it useless). Every IDE manages to display JDK Javadoc in the auto-completion popup. Why are people even considering IntelliJ? It took me 6 hours now to get basic things working that isn't necessary in _any_ other IDE.

Comment: CTRL-Q is the shortcut for quick documentation. Works in the editor, but also in the popups.

Answer (score 0):

When method suggestion start appearing, Use "**alt + mouse middle-click**" against one of the method that will display Quick Documentation, then use up/down key for other methods, it will display automatically.
[image]