# IntelliJ does not load JavaDoc

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

Before you close this question as a duplicate: I am very well aware of [answers like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053144/how-to-see-javadoc-in-intellij-idea).

However, the Quick Doc only provides the type information, like Class and so on.

This is because the jars we have no JavaDoc in them (When I *Ctrl* + *B* into them they don't have any JavaDoc).

With jars, I don't mean some internal ones, but rather Objects like `String` or `List`, which would provide a JavaDoc in Netbeans, but in IntelliJ that Doc is just missing.

Can you enable it somewhere that JavaDoc gets loaded with the jars?

Comment: Make sure you are using JDK for development not JRE.

Comment: Project Structure Settings → SDKs shows me that I use **jdk1.8.0_73**. Is there another place where I need to change it? @Ismail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Documentation feature works using the sources attached to the JDK configuration like this:

[image: sources]

Try to reinstall the JDK, remove it from IntelliJ IDEA and add it again. Double check `src.zip` is added in the Sourcepath.