# IntelliJ - show javadocs in autocomplete menu without keyboard shortcut

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ when you use the dot operator it shows you a list of class members e.g. `Arrays.`.

Then you can use your keyboard shortcut (e.g. `ctrl + Q`) to show the Javadocs of each member.

I find it annoying to have to press the shortcut every time, is there a way to automatically show the Javadocs of the class members as soon as the menu is opened by the dot operator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij IDEA show javadoc automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934876/intellij-idea-show-javadoc-automatically)

Comment: It is already mentioned in Jetbrain webpage http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2010/07/autopopup-documentation-feature/ called auto popup doc

Comment: Hm, while the description seems like what i am look in those 2 links, nothing different happens with that setting.

Comment: The setting has no effect on automatic code completion popup, only for explicitly invoked code completion (ctrl + space); this is discussed in the mentioned other question, including a link to the issue in the Jetbrains bugtracker.