# What is the difference between Quick documentation and Autopopup documentation in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, autocomplete

In my Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2017.1  I find two similar options:

- Show quick documentation on mouse move
- Autopopup documentation

Let's localize them:

- File → Settings → Editor → General → General → **Show quick documentation on mouse move**

[image]

I see in [Viewing Inline Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/viewing-inline-documentation.html):

> Quick Documentation Lookup helps you get quick information for any symbol or just method signature information, provided that this symbol has been supplied with documentation comments in the applicable format.

and then:

> You can configure IntelliJ IDEA to automatically invoke the suggestions list, without having to call basic completion explicitly. To do this, in the main menu select File | Settings (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), on the left choose Editor | General | Code Completion, and select the Autopopup code completion option.

- File → Settings → Editor → General → Code Completion → **Autopopup documentation** (*for explicitly invoked completion)*.

[image]

Mentioned in [Auto-Completing Code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/auto-completing-code.html):

> Basic code completion helps you complete names of classes, methods, fields, and keywords within the visibility scope. When you invoke code completion, IntelliJ IDEA analyses the context and suggests the choices that are reachable from the current caret position.

---

The first one shows on mouse move above the given text. The second one shows on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> as shown in [Intellij IDEA show javadoc automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7934876/1983854).

However, I do not see the difference between them when working normally on my Python projects, for example if I define my own class `Foo` and I either press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> on the `Foo` from `f = Foo()`.

Comment: There is no difference, it's the same feature invoked using different ways.

Comment: @CrazyCoder uhms, so documentation == quick documentation somehow? It gets to [confuse people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615516/intellij-tooltip-shows-javadocs/36449603#comment75426482_36449603), specially by being placed in different places.

Comment: Yes, it's the same as described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11053374/104891.

Comment: I see, thanks @CrazyCoder - would you be so kind to add it as an answer so new people accessing the question see the response better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between the quick documentation and autopopup documentation, it's the same feature invoked using different ways [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11053374/104891).