# Android Studio: Javadoc is empty on hover

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, javadoc

I have moved from Eclipse to Android Studio recently, and am liking it. However, I miss the Javadoc on hover feature from Eclipse.

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615516/intellij-tooltip-shows-javadocs) to add the functionality, however, my hovers contain no Javadoc. If I use my documentation shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> it will show the documentation correctly, however, I really want it to come up in the Tooltip.

Below is a screenshot of what I see. Clearly, there should be a Javadoc on this method.

[image]

I see this on all methods/variables. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: there are a lot of things other than 'Gradle Build Running' that annoy and frustrate  you a lot

Answer (score 247, accepted):

Turns out the docs hover page was simply resized to be very short. Carefully moving the mouse down to the bottom of the hover page allowed me to resize it.

Even after resizing it though, I still see it return to it's tiny size quite often... I'm glad I have my docs back, even if it does mean dealing with this annoyance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Android Studio is making me crazy in so many ways.

Comment: Now that I used your tip, the stupid hover over also "documents" auto replaced resources and thus hides the R.id. values... :( I want JavaDoc on mouse over, but I do NOT want to have this other nice feature destroyed... *sigh*

Comment: I think we **all** do agree that Android Studio totally **sucks** for that kind of details. I miss Eclipse so much ! :(

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to avoid it getting constantly resized? This is a general problem with intelliJ it seems.

Comment: I've gone through a few installs of Studio at this point, this bug has stopped appearing for me. Maybe you can try a fresh install too, but I can't guarantee anything.

Comment: Brilliant, that is the issue. I was like WTH I checked that option "mouse hover" but still no docs and when I entered the class I found the docs so where is it. RESIZING bug in Android Studio

Comment: Still experiencing this (2.0)... Why would it default to such a small size... They should include a way to set the default size...

Comment: I'm using Intellij IDEA 15 Ultimate and this ultimately solved the same problem I had. Thanks!

Comment: I really do not miss Eclipse. JetBrains IDEs are so nice (my impression after working about 2 months with Android Studio and also PyCharm).
The only thing: On Windows it was incredibly laggy even after increasing the allocated heap size. But on Ubuntu 14 it works like a charm ;)

Comment: Thanks! Can believe it still persists 3 years later!

Comment: I really think Google threw the baby out with the bath water with Android Studio. I'll admit ADT on eclipse wasn't perfect but I'd rather they had just improved the Eclipse platform rather than move to what seem to be like an IDE that does too much hand holding and contains a lot of bloat. The default settings in AS just blow my mind. Spell checking of variableNames why??

Answer (score 128):

You don't need to edit the idea.properties file, just go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> General, then check "Show quick doc on mouse move" in the right pane.

Comment: This works perfectly.  When I first tried to mouse-over after enabling this setting, the popup window was shorter than I wanted, so I grabbed the corner of it and expanded it -- and guess what?!  So far it remembers the size I expanded it to on subsequent mouse-overs!

I even closed Android Studio and restarted it, and my popup window size persisted perfectly :)

Comment: Why is this not on by default?! I was almost ready to go back to eclipse! :P

Comment: This hover works but can conflict with showing an error on the same line and can be difficult to get get the desired one open.  Eclipse did  the hovering javadoc and errors so much better!

Comment: Why are they hesitating to make this a default behavior?

Comment: On a Mac this is under Preferences > Editor > General

Answer (score 53):

### Android Studio 1.2.2

`File > Settings > Editor > General > Show quick doc on mouse move`.

[image: screenshot]

### Android Studio 1.0

`File > Settings > IDE Settings Editor > Show quick doc on mouse move`.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can't belive this is still needed on AS 1.5. Thank you

Comment: I had the same prob. I don't know why this isn't the installed default!

Answer (score 16):

Did U downloaded Documentation for Android SDK from Android SDK Manager?

[image]

If you installed the Documentation you will get like this when you press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Yes, the documentation is installed. It also shows up correctly when I use my 'quick documentation' hotkey

Comment: I do get the documentation popup but it is not syntax highlighted, any idea why it's not syntax highlighted? http://stackoverflow.com/q/23086511/238768