# Android Studio not showing javadoc with CTRL + Q but available in source

Tags: java, android, android-studio, documentation, javadoc

Before reading, this is NOT a duplicate of any other related Android Studio javadoc not working, in my case I can see it but only in the source, which means I can't check the javadoc without going to the class. Also this is weird because it seems to happen only to only some classes, but the ones it is working with are in a very small amount. To make it clear here are some screenshots.
First, when it's not working:
[image: Screenshot showing javadoc not working]

Then when it's working:

[image: Screenshot showing javadoc working]

Any ideas? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Related **non-duplicate** post here that solved my similar isue: [Android Studio: javadoc is empty on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16947002/383414)

Comment: Looks like your issue is Yet Another Annoying Android Studio Bug...