# Android Studio shows useless docs instead of JavaDocs on hover

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

How do I get Android Studio to show JavaDocs when I hover over a method?

I'm running Android Studio and have ["Show quick doc on mouse move" enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20746942/24396). However, when I hover over a method it just shows some useless docs.

[image]

I would like it to show the actual JavaDocs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Keep holding ctrl key in your keyboard and hover over the method you want to see the JavaDocs for it, then simply click on it.

**Edit:**

You may also check this link: [Android Studio: javadoc is empty on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818952/android-studio-javadoc-is-empty-on-hover)

Comment: I'm not pressing the alt key to being with. But when I do hold down the alt key nothing different happens.

Comment: Sorry I forgot, it's ctrl key. If it still doesn't show anything, try ctrl + q.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that does not involve pressing down a key, see my original question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615516

Comment: Check the accepted answer in my edited answer's link please. Hope that helps.