# How to open android documentation and samples of code in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have downloaded all documentation with SDK manager help. But how can I open this documentation and the samples of code in Android Studio after downloading?

Comment: Import them into eclipse. Go to export -> gradle project. Import that into AS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to make sure the documentation is added to Android Studio.

Go to `File` -> `Project Structure`. Under the `Platform Settings` heading, add or select an `Android Platform`. Go to the `Documentation Paths` tab and make sure the path to your SDK's documenation folder is added there - it should be `[SDK]\docs\reference`, where `[SDK]` is the full path to your SDK installation. If it is not there add it manually.

Once this is done, use Ctrl+F1 while your cursor is on the item you want to display help for.

The samples have not been ported to Android Studio yet, but I'm sure google will get around to it at some point. For now follow the instructions in the comments by  androidika (you will need a copy of Eclipse installed).

Comment: Maybe you know is there feature like in eclipse when you click or into method or class or any variable, ide showing a small window with documentation.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but if you press `Ctrl+Q` (on PC) or `Ctrl+J` (on Mac) then the JavaDoc for the current item under the cursor is displayed. NOTE: You might also be able to make this happen on hover - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16357065/1326821).

Comment: I am getting the documentation popup but there is no Syntax highlighting in the popup. I have asked this question here, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23086511/238768

Comment: This is removed with the newer version of Android Studio starting with 4.0

Answer (score 17):

According to [Android Studio Tips and Tricks](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html), you can press `Ctrl+Q` to show docs for selected API under Windows or `F1` under Mac.

For the samples , you can use eclipse to export to Android Studio.

Answer (score 7):

In Android Studio you need to download javadoc dependency which is part of sdk.

If you enable documentation to appear while writing code in android studio by navigating to

File-> Settings-> Editor-> General-> Other

and

selecting(check box) Show Quick documentation on mouse move, you would get irritating after some time because it will come out automatically you when you would be writing code.

So, I think we should go to alternative ways by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>(on Ubuntu at least I am not sure of other environments). This way when you would feel help you can simply use the simple command.

Comment: Ctrl + Q works on Windows as well. Not sure about mac.

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to find this setting in the latest build of android studio, and after wasting a lot of time I finally found out that now the ide automatically finds the documentation, which can be opened with shift+f1 on a method.

Comment: What is "latest build" for you? I have Android Studio 2.3.3 for Linux and `Shift-F1` is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Now a days once you Import project in Android studio, it will automatically shows docs. But on mouse hover you want to expand it.

[image]

Docs hover page was simply resized very short like the above, it looks like docs is not avail. But when I Carefully moving the mouse down to the bottom of the hover page allowed me to resize it.