# Quick documentation in Android Studio is not syntax highlighted

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

I recently switched to Android Studio from Eclipse and I noticed that the Quick Documentation popup in Android Studio does not syntax highlight the Android documentation. How do I enable this? I have looked everywhere online and still have no solution.I am on Android Studio 0.5.4 on Mac OS Mavericks 10.9.2

[image: No syntax highlighting for Android API documentation in Android Studio]

Comment: Do you get that popup with out pressing a Ctrl-Q?

Comment: @rekire No, I hate popup on mouseover. I instead press `Ctrl+J` to launch the popup. I also noted that Fetching documentation... takes more than 2 seconds sometimes.

Comment: Well I love that hover popups, but I never figgered out how to enable it in AS. But I don't know how to enable the highlighting.

Comment: @rekire Here you go, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16619709/238768

Comment: Bizarrely on my Mac, you need to do F1 to get that ... ??

Comment: @JoeBlow You can easily change that keyboard shortcut under Keymap section of Android Studio Preferences :) I use `Shift+Cmd+D` to show the quick Documentation as `F1` is difficult to press as it also involves pressing the `fn` key. OR You can use `F3` key as I don't really use to for the Expose gesture. I selectively disable some of my F-keys using Function Flip. Get it here http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/

Comment: For sure, @kpsfoo thanks!  My only problem now is making the @!$@#$ Overflow button appear in the action bar.  Good grief  :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday's update to Android Studio 0.5.5 fixed the problem for me! Seems it must be a glitch affecting version 0.5.4 only!