# How do I POST a JSON array and get a JSON object in response using preferably android Volley?

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, android-volley

The API I need to post to needs a JSONArray but is responding with a JSONObject. Unfortunately from what I can tell the Android Volley library has no method for this.

Is there a way to write a custom request and how would this be done to do what I explained above?

If it can not be done with Volley, how would you suggest I do it?

The method would look like this I believe:

//The array:

```
JSONArray itemArray = new JSONArray();

    try {

        for (MenuItem menuItem : listOfItems) {
            JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Item ID--> " + menuItem.getId());
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Item Quantity--> " + menuItem.getNumOrdered());
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Item Price Lvl--> " + 
            menuItem.getPrice_levels().get(0).getId().toString());
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Item Comments--> " + 
            menuItem.getSpecialInstructions());

            item.put("menu_item", menuItem.getId());
            item.put("quantity", menuItem.getNumOrdered());
            item.put("price_level", 
            menuItem.getPrice_levels().get(0).getId().toString());
            item.put("comment", menuItem.getSpecialInstructions());

            JSONArray discounts = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject discount = new JSONObject();
            discount.put("discount", null);

            item.put("discounts", discounts);

            JSONArray modifiers = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject modifier = new JSONObject();
            modifier.put("modifier", 
            menuItem.getModifierGroups().get(0).getId());

            item.put("modifiers", modifiers);


            itemArray.put(item);
        }
```

//The volley request

```
JsonArrayRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
url, itemArray, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {

                        finalized();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.v("volley ex", e.toString());
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.v("volley error", error.toString());

                }
            }) {


        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {


            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Api-Key", "api key");
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

            return headers;
        }

    };
    requestQueue.add(jsArrayRequest);

}
```

//The menuitem class

```
package com.garcon.garcon;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MenuItem implements Serializable {

public String id;
public String name;
public Integer price;
protected ArrayList<PriceLevel> price_levels;
protected Boolean in_stock;
protected int modifier_groups_count;
protected ArrayList<ModifierGroup> mGroups;

//not defined in API but will give Category's ID to MenuItem
protected String categoryID;

//user defined variable
public int numOrdered = 0;
private String specialInstructions = "";

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814076/how-to-make-intellij-show- 
//eclipse-like-api-documentation-on-mouse-hover
/**
 * Complete constructor for MenuItem.
 *
 * @param  id The menu item’s id as stored in the POS. Sometimes a compound 
 value derived from other data
 * @param  name The name of the Menu Item as stored in the POS
 * @param  price The price, in cents
 * @param  price_levels Array of Hashes (id String Price Level Identifier, 
 price Integer The price of the menu item at this price level, in cents)
 * @param  in_stock Whether or not the item is currently available for order.
 * @param  mGroups Modifier Groups associated with the Menu Item.
 * @param  modifier_groups_count The number of Modifier Groups associated 
 with the Menu Item.
 * @param  categoryID parent category's id NOT name
 */

public MenuItem(String id, String name, Integer price, ArrayList<PriceLevel> 
price_levels,
                Boolean in_stock, ArrayList<ModifierGroup> mGroups, Integer 
modifier_groups_count, String categoryID){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.price_levels = price_levels;
    this.in_stock = in_stock;
    this.mGroups = mGroups;
    this.modifier_groups_count = modifier_groups_count;

    this.categoryID = categoryID;

}

public ArrayList<PriceLevel> getPrice_levels() {
    return price_levels;
}

public void setPrice_levels(ArrayList<PriceLevel> price_levels) {
    this.price_levels = price_levels;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
String getCategoryID() {
    return categoryID;
}
public Integer getPrice(){
    return this.price;
}
ArrayList<ModifierGroup> getModifierGroups(){ return this.mGroups;}

int getNumOrdered(){return this.numOrdered;}
void setNumOrdered(int amount){
    numOrdered = amount;
}
String getSpecialInstructions(){return this.specialInstructions;}
void setSpecialInstructions(String instructions){
    specialInstructions = instructions;
}

static class ModifierGroup implements Serializable{
    private String id, name;
    private Integer minimum, maximum;
    private boolean required;
    private ArrayList<ItemModifier> modifier_list;

    public ModifierGroup(String id, String name, int minimum, int maximum, 
    boolean required, ArrayList<ItemModifier> modifier_list){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.minimum = minimum;
        this.maximum = maximum;
        this.required = required;
        this.modifier_list = modifier_list;
    }

    public ModifierGroup(){}

        String getId(){return id;}
        String getName(){return name;}
        Integer getMinimum(){return minimum;}
        Integer getMaximum(){return maximum;}
        boolean isRequired(){return required;}
        ArrayList<ItemModifier> getModifierList(){ return 
        this.modifier_list;}

        static class ItemModifier implements Serializable{
            private String id, name;
            private Integer price_per_unit;
            private ArrayList<PriceLevel> priceLevelsList;
            //user defined variable
            private boolean added = false;

            public ItemModifier(String id, String name, Integer 
            price_per_unit, ArrayList<PriceLevel> priceLevelsList){
                this.id = id;
                this.name = name;
                this.price_per_unit = price_per_unit;
                this.priceLevelsList = priceLevelsList;
            }

            String getId(){return id;}
            String getName(){return name;}
            Integer getPricePerUnit(){return price_per_unit;}
            ArrayList<PriceLevel> getPriceLevelsList(){return 
            priceLevelsList;}
            boolean isAdded(){ return added;}
            void setAdded(boolean b){added = b;}

        }

        static class ItemModifierGrouped extends ItemModifier implements 
            Serializable{
            private int group_id;
            public ItemModifierGrouped(String id, String name, Integer 
                price_per_unit, ArrayList<PriceLevel> priceLevelsList, int 
                group_id){
                super(id,name,price_per_unit,priceLevelsList);
                this.group_id = group_id;
            }
        }

}

public static class PriceLevel implements Serializable{
    public  String id;
    public  Integer price;
    public PriceLevel(){}
    public PriceLevel(String id, Integer price){
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getId(){return id;}
    public Integer getPrice(){return price;}
}

}
```

Comment: Your response can have JSONArray you just have to json-parse your response. I don't think that JSONArray can be returned as a response unless you have custom Volley request written.

Comment: Hi Alex can u post your desired JSON request along with question?

Comment: @AadityaBrahmbhatt Yes, to do this with Volley I will need a custom Volley request. I am unsure how to write it though and would like help with that. I am willing to use a different android library if that would work better.

Comment: The JSON request posted is the desired JSON request. The JsonArrayRequest library does not have a method for posting a JsonArray and getting a JsonObject in response. The request posted, POST a JsonArray and expects a JsonObject in response. @RavindraKushwaha

Comment: This example should help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014210/how-to-post-request-parameters-when-using-jsonarrayrequest-in-volley

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
 final String httpUrl = url;

 Log.i(TAG,httpUrl.toString());
    try{
        JSONArray parametersForPhp = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put(key,"0");
        jsonObject.put("key","");
        jsonObject.put(key,sharedPreferences.getString(PATIENT_ID,BLANK));
        jsonObject.put(APP_LANGUAGE,sharedPreferences.getString(APP_LANGUAGE,BLANK));

        parametersForPhp.put(jsonObject);

        JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, httpUrl, parametersForPhp,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.i(TAG,response.toString());
                        if (response==null){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Try Again!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {
                            try {
                                //you code
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        RequestQueueSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(arrayRequest);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```