# How to keep popup on one screen in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, multiple-monitors

When I type dot and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, I see a pop-up with list of possible methods.

when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> i see another pop-up with javadoc for the selected method.

The problem is half of the popup is on the one screen and second half is on another screen. it's unreadable. how to make the pop-up stay on one screen?

ubuntu 14.04, mate, 2 monitors (extended desktop), intellij 2016.1.1

Answer (score 0):

The pin is your friend!

[image]

Press that pin in the top right corner to "Open as tool window"!

[image]

From that moment on, the documentation will always appear in that specific window. Just resize it and place it somewhere in your screen where it does not interfere with other things. From that moment on, every time you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> the documentation will appear in that window.

[image]

---

Also, note you can change the font size:

[image]

But it may be more handy to drag the popup with the mouse:

[image]

Comment: making font smaller is not an option. moving manually is what i'm doing right now but it kills productivity

Comment: @piotrek see my updated answer! Using the pin is the solution. You get the documentation in another window.

Comment: but how can this be undone?... in my intellij-14, after using the pin just like you have described, the icon doesn't ever show up in that top right corner anymore... So now even when I click outside the javadoc popup, the popup doesn't go away... To make it go away, I have to first click inside the popup then out again... The experience is too skewed and frustrating

Comment: @CodeBurner to me, in Intelij IDEA 2016, the pin toggles. This way, if you click it again when in a pop up, it goes back to the main window.