# Is it possible to access Spring Documentation from Intellij IDE?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, springdoc

I want to view Spring Documentation via Intellj's `View->Quick Documentation` features.
To achieve this, I have tried this following by using external documentation link:

> Ok, I've added the url of the Spring Framework docs. as instructed, but yet, when I do ctrl+Q on a Spring Framework item, it doesn't show any docs. on the pop-up above...
>
> Here is the url I used: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/

[Intellij Support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007679999-Is-there-a-way-to-add-Spring-Boot-docs-to-the-quick-docs-menu-)

But it is not working.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Quick Documentation

"Quick Documentation" is different from "External Documentation". For "Quick Documentation" you just need to configure your dependencies to include sources.

Do you have a Maven or Gradle project?

For Gradle and IntelliJ you can use the [gradle-intellij-plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin) in your `build.gradle(.kts)` file. It has a `downloadSources` option, which is true by default.

For Maven, there is an option to automatically download sources, documenation, and annotations in the IntelliJ settings under "Maven" > "Importing".

To see whether it's working or to do it manually, go to "Project Structure" > "Project Settings" > "Libraries" in IntelliJ. You can see and manually add or modify the source JARs and documentation URLs for all your libraries.

## External Documentation

For external documentation (opening JavaDoc in the browser), you can tell IntelliJ to download the JavaDoc with the [idea](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html) Gradle plugin like this:

```
idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true 
        //or in Gradle Kotlin DSL:
        //isDownloadJavaDoc = true
    }
}
```

For Maven the option is again in the IntelliJ settings.

Comment: OK, there is a setting for maven in IntelliJ. I updated the answer for you.

Comment: Thanks, I had to initiate download by Right Click the project ->Maven->Download Documentation. Now it is working perfectly.

Comment: Is there also a way to enable external documentation on the spring related classes (i.e. select a spring class type, use the 'external documentation' command to view its api in browser)? I configure the documentation path in project setting as https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/ but its not working

Comment: @hafan96 You can try it as described here: https://dzone.com/articles/gradle-goodness-download-javadoc-files-for-depende I'll update my answer too.

Comment: For those coming from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20746942/1243462 THIS is the correct way to get the Eclipse-style behaviour in IDEA.

If this ALONE doesn't work, you need to right click project root -> "Maven" -> "Download sources and Documentation" . Finally, "File" -> "Invalidate Caches" and restart.

Comment: @shikharraje you are repeating what mnhmilu said.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer for Gradle and Kotlin in 2024: that's what you should add to your `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
idea {
    module {
        isDownloadJavadoc = true
    }
}
```

also in that file make sure you have `idea` plugin activated in `plugins` section:

```
plugins {
    id("idea")
}
```

After that javadoc will be shown when you open:

- Quick Documentation (menu: `View –> Quick Documentation`, shortcut: `Ctrl + Q`)
- External Documentation (menu: `View –> External Documentation`, shortcut: `Shift + F1`)
- or hover your mouse over the code (this works if you have `Show quick documentation on hover` enabled in IntelliJ settings)