# Show JavaDoc hint in editor

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij shows method parameter information when Ctrl+P is pressed. Sometimes this is not enough and I need to see a JavaDoc of such a method. How do I do this? I could press Ctrl+B on methodand then IntelliJ goes to the source of the method. This is a bit too long as I need to press Ctrl+Alt+Left to get back to the place I was before in the editor window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ show JavaDocs tooltip on mouse over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615516/intellij-show-javadocs-tooltip-on-mouse-over)

Comment: I do not want to use mouse as IntelliJ is keyboard-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [Quick Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#inline-quick-documentation).

It can be shown either by

- hovering over the element of interest ([with a configurable delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615516/intellij-show-javadocs-tooltip-on-mouse-over))
- pressing a hot key when the caret is on the element of interest (also configurable via the keymap)

[image]